# Create nested procedure in Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I want to create a nested procedure where in the 1st procedure, I want to create a table dynamically with 2 columns and in the 2nd procedure, I want to insert values into that table.

Below is the code I am trying to use; what am I doing wrong?

```
CREATE  or replace PROCEDURE mytable (tname varchar2)
is
stmt varchar2(1000);
begin
stmt := 'CREATE TABLE '||tname || '(sname varchar2(20) ,sage number (4))';
execute immediate stmt;
end;
create PROCEDURE mytable1 (emp_name varchar2,emp_age number,tname varchar2)
is
stmt1 varchar2(1000);
begin
stmt1 := 'insert into '||tname||' values ('Gaurav' ,27)';
execute immediate stmt1;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to create a nested procedure here. You can do everything in a single procedure.

Note my use of bind variables in the [`execute immediate` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/executeimmediate_statement.htm#LNPLS01317)

```
create or replace procedure mytable (
    Ptable_name in varchar2
  , Pemp_name in varchar2
  , Pemp_age in number
     ) is

begin

   execute immediate 'create table ' || Ptable_name 
                      || ' (sname varchar2(20), sage number (4))';
   execute immediate 'insert into ' || Ptable_name 
                      || ' values (:emp_name, :emp_age)'
         using Pemp_name, Pemp_age;

end;
```

More generally, there's no need to use `execute immediate` at all; creating tables on the fly is indicative of a poorly designed database. If at all possible do not do this; create the table in advance and have a simple procedure to insert data, should you need it:

```
create or replace procedure mytable (
  , Pemp_name in varchar2
  , Pemp_age in number
     ) is

begin

   insert into my_table 
   values (Pemp_name, Pemp_age);

end;
```

I would highly recommend reading Oracle's chapter on [Guarding Against SQL Injection](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#BJECFFHD).

---

If you really feel like you *have* to do this as a nested procedure it would look like this; don't forget to call the nested procedure in the main one as the nested procedure isn't visible outside the scope of the first.

```
create or replace procedure mytable (
    Ptable_name in varchar2
  , Pemp_name in varchar2
  , Pemp_age in number
     ) is

  procedure myvalues (
       Pemp_name in varchar2
     , Pemp_age in number
       ) is
  begin
     execute immediate 'insert into ' || Ptable_name
                    || ' values (:emp_name, :emp_age)'
       using Pemp_name, Pemp_age;
  end;

begin

   execute immediate 'create table ' || Ptable_name
                      || ' (sname varchar2(20), sage number (4))';

   myvalues ( Pemp_name, Pemp_age);

end;
```

Please see Oracle's documentation on [PL/SQL subprograms](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/subprograms.htm)

Comment: can you also tell me how to enter the values while calling the above procedure from a jdbc code.
    
 public String name;
     public String username
    public Integer age;

 public String execute()
 {  
  
      Connection con;
 Statement stmt;
 ResultSet rs;

 Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");      con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","Gaurav","oracle");
    stmt=con.createStatement();
    CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall (begin mytable(....); end; );
}

Comment: I'm sorry but it's been a while since I've used JDBC and I've got nothing to test it on at the moment... there are other questions about parsing parameters in a statement on [so] though.